# How to configure postfix to send email from local domain to relay host and back?

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot, transport

I have smtp domain `example.com` and cloud relay SMTP host `relay.cloud.inc`. How can i configure and what should i use to achieve next:
When i send email from **user1@example.com** to **user2@example.com** email will route to `relay.cloud.inc` for security checks and go back to my `example.com`. Is in possible to achieve?

My stack is:

1. Postfix
2. Dovecot (with LMTP)

- I tried to use transport map in postfix, but i achieved email routing loop.

  In file **transport** set next config:

  ```
   example.com smtp:[relay.example.com]:25
  ```
- I tried send email traffic to custom content filter first, but i dont have needed result, i currently researching this variant.

Comment: What os do you use?

Comment: @Grim Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Please try to send an mail from command line. Look for send err

Comment: @Grim
There no errors. In fact, email just go to relay host, relay host make it's job and return email to my host, BUT as postfix trasport say that example.com MUST go to relay host this what postfix do - send email back. As the result it loops the email.